# I want to turn a message ticker script into a tip of the day script

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have a couple of message tickers that cycle through messages from a list stored in a .txt file. The messages cycle at a given rate (around every five seconds). What I want to do is change the js so that instead of reading every message in the .txt file, it wil only display the message relevant to the current day of the year. I am pretty sure that this portion of the js is what I need to change:

```
function tde_message(xmlfile, divId, divClass, delay, fadeornot){
    this.xmlfile=xmlfile
    this.messageid=divId
    var delay=(typeof delay=="number")? [delay] : delay
    this.delay=delay[0]
    this.refetchdelay=delay[1]
    this.mouseoverBol=0
    this.pointer=0
    this.opacitystring=(typeof fadeornot!="undefined")? "width: 100%; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(opacity=100); opacity: 1" : ""
    if (this.opacitystring!="") this.delay+=500
        this.opacitysetting=0.2
    this.messages=[]
    this.tdeobj=createTDEObj()
    document.write('<div id="'+divId+'" class="'+divClass+'"><div style="'+this.opacitystring+'">Initializing messages...</div></div>')
    this.getXMLfile()
}
```

I was thinking that I should replace the delays with something like:

```
get.date(this.day)
```

The problem is, I know so little about javascripts and applets that I have no idea where to start converting. Unfortunately, the person who gave me this script is no longer available to advise me and I am stuck begging for help. Can anyone show me how to properly call for a specific line of text from a file to display depending on the day of the year?